# C# VS2010 Not Entering For loop?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, for-loop

The following code is not entering the i for loop. I have had problems with my computer and VS2010. Is this a coding issue (I am a vb.net programmer programing c#.net) or a vb install issue?

```
            for(int hi = 1; hi > 10; hi++)
            {
                reply = pingsender.Send(ip, 500, buffer, options);
                avgtime += reply.RoundtripTime;
            }
            //EDIT:
            //All code except for issue taken offline due to company policy
            //sorry for any inconvience
```

This code is nested in four for loops (that all work) and is runnin, and is meant to put ping statistics in a list box. Sorry for the messy code, I comment and clean after I get the code working.

Thank you in advance for all of your hard work!

Comment: I see no i-loop... Also: check the l, c4 and cp4 variables. make sure they have the correct values.

Comment: Which loop is not being entered? `for(int hi = 1; hi > 10; hi++)`?  Then yes definitely, `1` is not greater than `10` so the body is never executed.

Comment: Not answering the question, but I really advice you to rename the variables to something meaningful. because this code as it stands more likely to be after applying some obfuscation "`k`, `i`, `l`, `hi`, `c4`.."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for(int hi = 1; hi > 10; hi++)
```

will never be true; fails at the first test, as `1` is not `> 10`.

The middle clause is (essentially) "while" - not "until". I suspect you need `< 10` (for 9 iterations) or `<= 10` (for 10 iterations).

Comment: Sleep Deprivation Coding FAIL! Thank you for making me realize that I probably need to lay off the caffine, and go to bed. =)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess why the code isn't entering your for loop.  (Especially since the code is just a snippet of the problem.)

I'd suggest that you place a breakpoint on your for loop, then check what the variables are set to.  It's always helpful to use your debugger for diagnosis.

Cheers!

Comment: Agg!  I was looking at the first for loop, not the second ; )